# Fetching rows based on two foreign id in jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, many-to-one

I am using PostgreSQL as database and I want to fetch all rows whose two column matches foreign key of another table.

I have mapped the relation in the table as:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "projects_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Projects projects;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "reports_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Reports reports;
```

This is CRUD method I have defined in the interface :

```
List<ProjectReportTask> findByProjectsIdAndReportsId(Long id, Long id2);
```

But when I call this method the list is empty rather in db I have records with both id present

Answer (score 0):

I do see anything wrong with the method naming. However, I have faced similar issues when my entity uses `@NaturalId`. So I would suggest you write the query manually.

```
@Query(value="SELECT prt FROM 
ProjectReportTask prt 
WHERE prt.projects.id = ?1 AND prt.reports.id = ?2 ")
List<ProjectReportTask> getProjectReportTask(Long id, Long id2);
```

Comment: I solved that problem thanks for your concern though.....I made a mistake in fetching wrong inputs I filled dummy data....above is the perfect implementation...though I would love to know what is @NaturalId in your case

Comment: In my case, `id` is primary key for `user`. This `id` is shared by `employee` using `@Mapsid`. This shared key is named as `userId` in the `Employee` table. `Employee` also has a id field which is annotated as `@NaturalId`. Now if I try to query using the CRUD method findById in the `Employee` repository, search is done on user_id rather than id by Spring.